# Web service restful api return table record count

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I am developing an android application where I am syncing the SQLite database on android device with my SQL server. I have done the same from multiple tutorials using Web Api to post and get the data from SQL server. I have never used a Web api controller before, hence don't know much about it.

I have used the tutorial at http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-android-ios-using-asp-net-web-api-2/

My syncing is working fine, but I just want to sync when the record count on Sqlite doesn't match with SQL server. For this I want to get the table record count from the Web api controller. I tried searching a lot, but not able to find examples.  Can you tell me how to post the count from a Web service and get it via my Dbhandler in Android.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

Comment: I created

     [HttpGet]
     public int GetCount()     
       {
                 int Count;
                 Count = dbContext.MP.Count();
                 return Count;
             }
  
  
and its working fine.